# IMB MQ 6 to 8 Migration

Tags: ibm-mq, java-11, spring-jms

I have a spring Project , and i migrate from **4.X** to **5.3** it's a parserMQ , we receive a messages from File MQ.

I have com.ibm.mq with the version **6.0.2.2**.
I will migrate ibm-mq to version **8** and i'm not sure if there is constraint with the version's server FileMQ.

Should i migrate the version of the server FileMQ ?

Comment: MQ v8 is out of support. Go with v9.2 or v9.3.

Comment: Also MQ 8 doesn't support Java 11, the system requirements shows only java 7 support.